# Border around last clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some `<img>` elements behave like `<input type="radio">` buttons (already managed that) and now I need to inform the user of his choice. To do that I want to make a `border` around the last selected image.

Please note that I have more than 1 row of radios so the user should be able to click on one image from the first row (it should stay highlighted) then he must be able to click on the second row and so on while his choices remain highlighted.

```
.product-info .option img:active
{
    border:1px solid #d9d1d5;
}
```

Example code

```css
.images img:active {
    border:3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you set up a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: give the active image a class instead

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wpaqv034/

Comment: using `outline` instead of `border` is closest to native behavior of checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a slightly different approach, not using any javascript. The basic idea is that you want to mimick radio-button, so let's use radio button (and label) functionality...

**HTML**

```
<div class="images">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" id="test1">
    <label for="test1">
        <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="2" id="test2">
    <label for="test2">
        <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="3" id="test3">
    <label for="test3">
        <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="4" id="test4">
    <label for="test4">
        <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {display:none;}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label img {border:3px solid #000;}
```

[And the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a54gec32/1/)

**Explanation**

When correctly set, a click on a label tag checks the associated radiobutton/checkbox (and puts focus on other types of fields). I use this default behaviour combined with the "adjacent sibling" CSS selector `+` and the `:checked` pseudo-selector to target the adjacent label and its `img` child. An added value of this is that you can totally post it as a form, it will post the radiobutton values...

Comment: Best method. Worked perfectly and extremely easy and fast to implement.

Answer (score 3):

### In principle

Simply detect the click event for qualifying elements, remove a class denoting selected state from all qualifying elements, and add to the one clicked.

```js
$('.radioImg').on('click', function() {
  $('.radioImg').removeClass('selected')
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.radioImg.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
<img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
<img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
```

### However

If you have multiple sets of this kind of thing, you can wrap within a parent element, change the selector to narrow by this, and use siblings to remove the class from the adjacent items. This represents a far more reusable implementation.

```js
$('div .radioImg').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.radioImg.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
  <img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
  <img class='radioImg' src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f62f93c13e2aad52fa08a693ce13da48?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery and check what ever image has the specific class like:

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
  //remove from all images imgClicked class
  $("img").removeClass("imgClicked");
  //add class to click image element
  $(this).addClass("imgClicked");
});
```

```css
.imgClicked {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=20%C3%9720&w=20&h=20" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=20%C3%9720&w=20&h=20" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=20%C3%9720&w=20&h=20" />
```

Comment: `$(this).hasClass("imgClicked")` is pointless, you already `$("img").removeClass("imgClicked");` above it.

Answer (score 0):

So Simple ! U can do it without extra css also.

```
$('.radioImg').on('click', function() {
  $('.radioImg').css("border","none")
  $(this).css("border","1px solid blue")
});
```

Comment: Using a css class is usually recommended and much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Know How You Made images go radio, Below is a complete solution:

HTML..

```
<label class="pinLabel"><input type="radio" name="radios" /><img src="abc.jpg" />Label Text </label>
```

CSS..

```
label.pinLabel > input{
display:none;
}

label.pinLabel > input:checked + img{
border :1px solid red;
}

 label.pinLabel > input + img{
 cursor:pointer;
 /* Rest default properties for image*/
}

label.pinLabel > input + img:hover{
cursor:pointer;
 /* Rest default properties for image on hover*/
}

label.pinLabel > input:disabled + img{
cursor: not-allowed;
 /* Rest default properties for image when Disabled*/
}
```

Hope it helps